# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Magento Stack Exchange has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Murtuza Zabuawala]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5525008104292352).

Comment: congrts @https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29731/murtuza-zabuawala

Comment: Thank you @AmitBera bhai

Comment: Congrats @MurtuzaZabuawala :)

Comment: Thank you @KeyurShah bhai

Comment: you deserved it buddy , good luck ; ) hope you are enjoying 'Mod' infront of your name, what a proud feeling....

Comment: Thank you @BabyinMagento :)

Comment: Many many congratulation @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: thank you @JitendraPatel

Comment: Congratulation @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: Thank you @PrincePatel bhai

Comment: Congratulations @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: Thank you @CharmiPatel

Comment: Congratulations @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: Thank you @PruthviRaval